# anonymous callback function in .animate() not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-callback

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem with this code is.  The animation itself works fine:

```
if (!list.is(':animated')) {
    list.animate(
        {"top": "+="+item_size},
        {queue:false, duration:speed},
        function() {
            alert();
        }
    ); // end of animate function

} //end of if statement
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up the two signatures of [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  You need to make the callback a part of the `options` argument:

```
if(!list.is(':animated')){
    list.animate({
        top: "+="+item_size
    }, //end of properties argument
    {
        queue: false, 
        duration: speed,
        complete: function(){
            alert();
        } //end of callback
    }  // end of options argument
    ); // end of animate function
} //end of if statement
```

Comment: *hits head on wall* Thanks so much for this!  I'm a newbie as of yesterday - can you tell? :P

Comment: @hugh We've all been there! If this answer has answered your question, you can mark it by clicking the empty tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: You've been ticked ;) Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Check the [API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you don't seem to be calling the function right:

```
.animate( properties, [ duration ], [ easing ], [ callback ] )
```

Guess this is how you should call it:

```
.animate( {"top": "+="+item_size}, speed, 'linear', function(){alert();});
```

Change `linear` to whatever easing function you need.

Comment: Thankyou so much!  I solved the problem a moment before these two posts by just removing the {queue: false, duration: speed} and replacing it with speed, but its great to know how I can include this parameter if i need to.